# How to make a Chrome Extension sleep for a time and post message on port

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout, sleep

In my extension, I want the extension wait for a time, because it changes something in the content and it mustn't be fast. 
I am using a sleep function, it is just a loop that breaks when the time comes but it makes my computer really slow. 
I used setTimeout method, but the extension says "port is not defined", because the code goes on when the setTimeout method is run, but I think the port stops connection. 
So, do you have any idea how I can make the code sleep without ruining the computer?

Sleep function

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {

  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
     for(var j=0;j<10000000;j++)
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            return;
    }
  }
}
```

Port codes

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");

  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("mesajjj");
    if (msg.joke == "Baslat"){
        setTimeout(firstwaiting, 5000);
        console.log("wait");
    }
  });

});

function firstwaiting(){
  port.postMessage({question: "waited"}); 
  console.log("waited, now goes on");
}
```

I get the "port is not defined at firstwaiting" error using the second way with the setTimeout method.
There is no problem in the connection, it works with sleep function but I need a better way.

I expect to have a delay without using too much of effort. I am trying it for days, but I couldn't find a way even on the net. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sleep` function doesn't actually sleep/wait, it just blocks the main thread of the page. In JavaScript the only proper way to sleep is setTimeout/setInterval and similar built-in functions.

Solution: don't use sleep() and simply pass the `port` to your timer callback as a parameter.

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    if (msg.joke == 'Baslat') {
      setTimeout(firstwaiting, 5000, port);
    }
  });
});

function firstwaiting(port) {
  port.postMessage({question: 'waited'});
}
```

Comment: You are my hero,  thanks a lot!! I was trying this for a long time :) I couldn't upvote btw, I don't have enough reputation.